# Backendless iOS: join equivalent for find

Tags: ios, database, backendless

I have this data model:

Album <--->> Photo <--->> Like <<---> User

I want to get the photos from specific Album and I want to attach Likes to them as well. I would like to have some equivalent of a Fetched Property, because I don't want to get an array of likes to each photo, I just want to have the one like.

Here's related Backendless support question:
http://support.backendless.com/topic/join-equivalent-for-find-fetched-properties

Comment: Do you mean you want each photo and its number of likes for a given album?

Comment: Yes, but that's not my question. My question is how to get one particular "Like" entity, that determines relationship between the current user and the photo. I want to know if I like the photo or not.

Comment: You are not clear. (In your question, your comment, or your linked posts.) Please explain what you want and give example input & output, including parameters and table definitions & contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply complex NSPredicate to the fetch request, it can analyse both the direct attributes of the target entity of a fetch and the attributes of its relationships

Try :

```
NSPredicate(format: "(albums = %@) AND (SUBQUERY(likes, $l, $l IN %@).@count > 0)", album, user.likes)
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use core data as it is using ORM it will satisfy all your needs